# Posting the Values from a ComboBox ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to post values from an AjaxToolKit ComboBox using ASP.NET 4.0.

Here is my code:

WebForm1

HTML

```
<body>
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server">
        </ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="true" PostBackUrl="~/WebForm2.aspx" />
    </div>
</body>
```

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ListItem tmpListItem = new ListItem("Item " + i.ToString());
        tmpListItem.Value = "Item " + i.ToString();
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(tmpListItem);
    }
}
```

WebForm2

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext tmpHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    string cmboBoxValue = tmpHttpContext.Request["ComboBox1"];
}
```

All I get for cmboBoxValue is null.

I am so frusterated because I know this must be simple. I am sure I have done this 100* in the past.

I looked here

[How to submit http form using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273998/how-to-submit-http-form-using-c-sharp)

but that did not help. It has to be submitted with the asp:Button.

Hopefully this is enough information for you to provide a response.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of another member I was able to uncover the answer. It can be found here:

[Get POST Values in ASP.NET using NameValueCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011905/get-post-values-in-asp-net-using-namevaluecollection)

Answer (score 0):

Provided code below:

Put this code on default.aspx page

```
<cc1:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="Suggest" AutoPostBack="True" DropDownStyle="Simple">
<asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Lanka</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Pak</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Aus</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Aps</asp:ListItem>
</cc1:ComboBox>
```

Put this code on button1 click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
         Label1.Text = "You selected" + ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text;       
    }
```

You can as well check out the link below and work on your CSS page. (read the answer thats checked off)

[AjaxControlToolkit, ComboBox style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691630/ajaxcontroltoolkit-combobox-style)

Comment: I don't think this is what I was looking for... Thanks though!